# Drupal 7 Views - How to use HTML code inside field labels?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Field labels in Views are assuming plain-text input and they are probably using [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) to encode special characters (didn't actually look at Views back-end).

How can HTML code be used inside labels?

Edit: I thought my question is clear. I don't want to rewrite fields, I want to use HTML code inside a label, that's all.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question right. Views has the option "Strip HTML tags If checked, all HTML tags will be stripped."     So by default html should be allowed in the fields and this should be true to the labels too. If you can put some more info up it will be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. While you can't use HTML input inside labels on the Views UI, you can customize a label inside a style output template.

e.g. for an "example" view that uses a table style output you would customize `views-view-table--example.tpl.php` and use a code like:

```php
//custom label for title field
$header['title'] = '<strong>Foo</strong> bar';
```

Comment: If you just need to wrap the text around an HTML tag, you have a bit of control over the title HTML in the field config, through the `Customize label HTML` checkbox in the `Style settings` section. These are very limited options, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is adding a new process function for the particular view format, and make your changes in that preprocess function.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function example_theme_registry_alter (&$theme_registery) {
    $theme_registery['views_view_table']['preprocess functions'][] = 'example_alter_table_header';
}

function example_alter_table_header(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    $vars['header']['field_some_title'] = 'HELLO<br/>WORLD';
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a little bit more complex than my initial solution, but the approach would prove itself really useful when there is a need to override the same label(s) over multiple views and some similar scenarios. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you could use `Rewrite output` option for that field.

Comment: No I can't use that. That would only rewrite the contents of a field, but what I need is to have HTML code inside a label. Your solution can be considered a work-around, but which wouldn't work in case of a Table style views. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

This has got nothing to do with 'strip html', ignore that.

Views fields have 'rewrite' functions in them for just this reason. So that you rewrite the html output and then use a token to reinsert the dynamic element.

So to rewrite field, wrapping it in an h1 tag you might do something like this...

Edit your field. In D7 Views 3 you see a toggle section under 'Rewrite Results'. Open this and tick 'Rewrite the output of this field'.

In the big box under it type:

```
<h1>[title]</h1>
```

And that's it. Simple. When the view is redended your title text will be wrapped in h1 tags.

The tokens you can use in the rewrite rule are listed in the toggle called 'replacement patterns' a bit lower down - they change depending on what type of field it is.

Comment: I'm not a beginner with Views, I know how to rewrite fields. The problem is I don't know how to "rewrite" labels. Like I answered to @Marius Ilie, this is only a work-around, which wouldn't work in case of a Table style views.

Answer (score -4):

Views 7.x-3.3

```
views/theme/theme.inc:269:      $object->label = check_plain($view->field[$id]->label());

views/theme/theme.inc:498:      $label = check_plain(!empty($fields[$field]) ? $fields[$field]->label() : '');
```

I edit the module theme/theme.inc file: remove the check_plain

Comment: You should [never hack core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) or contributed modules to achieve your goals.